# Windows 10 UWP XAML stowed_exception_802b000a_my_app.dll!windows::ui::xaml::iapplicationstatics__impl::stubclass.loadcomponent

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have a problem with a Windows 10 UWP Store App.

In the app are two pages (Page1 and Page2) with similar xaml controls, but one page (Page1) cause a lot of problems while testing the app by microsoft. If they try to start the app the initialization of Page1 throw an exception. When I remove one specific xaml control all is fine, but Page2 contains exactly the same controls and works perfectly. On my local machine I have no exceptions, no warnings, the windows certification kit say the app has no problems and I can't reproduce the exception.

When I remove the AppBarButtons from the CommandBar on Page1, the test Microsoft testing guy has no exception. The similar CommandBar on Page2 cause no exception on the computer of the test guy.

Xaml code of Page1 (which has the problem):

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyApp.Page1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar x:Name="cbCommandBar">

            <AppBarButton x:Name="pageBack" Label="Zurück" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="pageBack_Click">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Previous"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>

            <AppBarButton x:Name="pageNext" Label="Vor" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="pageNext_Click">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Next"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>

            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton x:Name="firstPage" Label="Erste Seite" Click="firstPage_Click"/>
            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
</Page>
```

Xaml code of Page2:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyApp.Page2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar x:Name="cbCommandBar">

            <AppBarButton x:Name="downloadImage" Content="Herunterladen" Label="Herunterladen" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="downloadImage_Click">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Download"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>

            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton x:Name="viewInBrowser" Label="Webansicht" Click="viewInBrowser_Click"/>
            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
</Page>
```

The exception:

```
stowed_exception_802b000a_my_app.dll!windows::ui::xaml::iapplicationstatics__impl::stubclass.loadcomponent
```

In the Windows Dev Center I can see the following call stack:
Frame   Bild    Funktion    Versatz

```
0   combase.dll RoOriginateErrorW   0x000000000000004E  
1   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::ErrorHelper::OriginateError   0x000000000000014C  
2   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CJupiterErrorServiceListener::NotifyErrorAdded  0x0000000000000192  
3   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CErrorService::AddError 0x0000000000000140  
4   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CErrorService::ReportParserError    0x0000000000000126  
5   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll ParserErrorService::ReportError 0x0000000000000146  
6   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll ParserErrorReporter::SetError   0x000000000000007E  
7   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll ObjectWriterErrorService::ReportError   0x0000000000000064  
8   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll BinaryFormatObjectWriter::SetValueOnCurrentInstance 0x000000000000087D  
9   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll BinaryFormatObjectWriter::WriteNode 0x0000000000000418  
10  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CParser::LoadXamlCore   0x0000000000000536  
11  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CCoreServices::ParseXamlWithExistingFrameworkRoot   0x0000000000000133  
12  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CApplication::LoadComponent 0x000000000000023E  
13  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll Application_LoadComponent   0x00000000000000C0  
14  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::FrameworkApplication::LoadComponent   0x00000000000000C7  
15  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::FrameworkApplicationFactory::LoadComponentWithResourceLocationImpl    0x0000000000000071  
16  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::FrameworkApplicationFactory::LoadComponentWithResourceLocation    0x000000000000004D  
17  MyApp.McgInterop.dll    McgInterop::ComCallHelpers.ComCall__HRESULT 0x000000000000008D  
18  MyApp.McgInterop.dll    Windows::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics__Impl::StubClass.LoadComponent   0x0000000000000074  
19  MyApp.exe   MyApp::Page1.InitializeComponent    0x000000000000005E  
20  MyApp.exe   MyApp::Page1..ctor  0x00000000000000AC  
21  MyApp.exe   MyApp::App..ctor    0x0000000000000083  
22  MyApp.exe   MyApp::Program::__c._Main_b__0_0    0x0000000000000019  
23  MyApp.McgInterop.dll    Windows::UI::Xaml::WindowSizeChangedEventHandler.Invoke 0x000000000000000F  
24  MyApp.McgInterop.dll    McgInterop::ReverseComSharedStubs.Proc_TArg0___System.__Canon_  0x000000000000005A  
25  MyApp.McgInterop.dll    Windows::UI::Xaml::ApplicationInitializationCallback__Impl::Vtbl.Invoke__STUB   0x0000000000000037  
26  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::FrameworkApplication::MainASTAInitialize  0x00000000000000A7  
27  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::FrameworkView::Initialize 0x0000000000000069  
28  twinapi.appcore.dll Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::CreateAndInitializeFrameworkView  0x00000000000000A7  
29  twinapi.appcore.dll _lambda_84f6292064cee6c4c814a3a064a63b95_::operator 0x00000000000001B4  
30  twinapi.appcore.dll _lambda_fe571ab0da94534d32388f0f07e67faa_::operator 0x0000000000000044  
31  SHCore.dll  _WrapperThreadProc  0x00000000000000C4  
32  kernel32.dll    BaseThreadInitThunk 0x0000000000000014  
33  ntdll.dll   RtlUserThreadStart  0x0000000000000021
```

I can't find an explanantion for this problem.

Maybe someone has an idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have test the XAML code for page1 and page2 it's work fine for me .

can you provide me the code behind for the page 1 .

the sdk version that you are using for this project .

thank's .

Comment: Ok thanks, yes on my computer it works also perfectly.

Here are the version information:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02046 

Visual Studio Tools für Universelle Windows-Apps   14.0.25527.01 

The code behind Page1 is simple, I request data from a Http-API and output the result in a grid (in the example I removed it). When the user use one of the AppbarButtons I start a new request just with different parameters like current page index + 1.

Comment: I also tested the application in a virtual machine and it works. 

From the Windows Dev Center I can download a mini dump, but that dump is not detailed enough to load it in VS and see more than the call stack.