# How to diagnostic XAML stowed_exception 802B000A?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, visual-studio-app-center

I published an app in Microsoft Store and MS App center reports me the following exception :

```
stowed_exception 802B000A.
```

I see other people facing same type or issue ([Windows 10 UWP XAML stowed_exception_802b000a_my_app.dll!windows::ui::xaml::iapplicationstatics__impl::stubclass.loadcomponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593112/windows-10-uwp-xaml-stowed-exception-802b000a-my-app-dllwindowsuixamliapp) ) but my stacktrace is a little bit different : no code from my app appear, only XAML framework component.

How to deal with this type of exception ?
Full stacktrace bellow.
Thanks in advance for help.

```
1   unknown.dll [StowedException]() +0x0000000000000000
2   combase.dll RoOriginateErrorW() error.cpp:542
3   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::ErrorHelper OriginateError() errorhelper.cpp:680
4   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CJupiterErrorServiceListener NotifyErrorAdded() jupitercontrol.cpp:1069
5   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CErrorService AddError() errorservice.cpp:657
6   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CErrorService ReportParserError() errorservice.cpp:818
7   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll ParserErrorService ReportError() parsererrorservice.cpp:198
8   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll ObjectWriterErrorService WrapErrorWithParserErrorAndRethrow() objectwritererrorservice.cpp:131
9   Windows.UI.Xaml.dll BinaryFormatObjectWriter SetValueOnCurrentInstance() binaryformatobjectwriter.cpp:654
10  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll BinaryFormatObjectWriter WriteNode() binaryformatobjectwriter.cpp:178
11  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CTemplateContent LoadXbfVersion2() templatecontent.cpp:668
12  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CTemplateContent Load() templatecontent.cpp:463
13  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CFrameworkTemplate LoadContent() template.cpp:103
14  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CControlTemplate LoadContent() template.cpp:226
15  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CFrameworkElement ApplyTemplate() framework.cpp:1314
16  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CContentPresenter ApplyTemplate() contentpresenter.cpp:600
17  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CFrameworkElement InvokeApplyTemplate() framework.cpp:1167
18  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CFrameworkElement MeasureCore() framework.cpp:1454
19  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement MeasureInternal() uielement.cpp:3984
20  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3810
21  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::UIElement MeasureImpl() uielement_partial.cpp:384
22  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::UIElementGenerated Measure() uielement.g.cpp:2794
23  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::ModernCollectionBasePanel Generate() moderncollectionbasepanel_partial.cpp:1368
24  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::ModernCollectionBasePanel RunGenerate() moderncollectionbasepanel_partial.cpp:888
25  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::ModernCollectionBasePanel RunVirtualization() moderncollectionbasepanel_partial.cpp:615
26  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::ModernCollectionBasePanel MeasureOverride() moderncollectionbasepanel_partial.cpp:516
27  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::FrameworkElementGenerated MeasureOverrideProtected() frameworkelement.g.cpp:864
28  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::FrameworkElement MeasureOverrideFromCore() frameworkelement_partial.cpp:260
29  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CFrameworkElement MeasureCore() framework.cpp:1490
30  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement MeasureInternal() uielement.cpp:3984
31  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3810
32  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::UIElement MeasureImpl() uielement_partial.cpp:384
33  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::UIElementGenerated Measure() uielement.g.cpp:2794
34  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::ItemsPresenter MeasureOverride() itemspresenter_partial.cpp:587
35  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::FrameworkElementGenerated MeasureOverrideProtected() frameworkelement.g.cpp:864
36  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::FrameworkElement MeasureOverrideFromCore() frameworkelement_partial.cpp:260
37  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CFrameworkElement MeasureCore() framework.cpp:1490
38  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement MeasureInternal() uielement.cpp:3984
39  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3810
40  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CControl MeasureOverride() control.cpp:389
41  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CItemsControl MeasureOverride() itemscontrol.cpp:313
42  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CFrameworkElement MeasureCore() framework.cpp:1507
43  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement MeasureInternal() uielement.cpp:3984
44  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3810
45  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
46  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
47  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
48  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CGrid MeasureOverride() grid.cpp:1134
49  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CFrameworkElement MeasureCore() framework.cpp:1507
50  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement MeasureInternal() uielement.cpp:3984
51  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3810
52  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CGrid MeasureCellsGroup() grid.cpp:426
53  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CGrid MeasureOverride() grid.cpp:1355
54  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CFrameworkElement MeasureCore() framework.cpp:1507
55  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement MeasureInternal() uielement.cpp:3984
56  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3810
57  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
58  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
59  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
60  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
61  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
62  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
63  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
64  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
65  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
66  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
67  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
68  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
69  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
70  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
71  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
72  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
73  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
74  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
75  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
76  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
77  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
78  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
79  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
80  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CUIElement Measure() uielement.cpp:3891
81  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CLayoutManager UpdateLayout() layoutmanager.cpp:251
82  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CCoreServices NWDrawTree() xcpcore.cpp:7107
83  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CCoreServices NWDrawMainTree() xcpcore.cpp:6900
84  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CWindowRenderTarget Draw() windowrendertarget.cpp:138
85  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CXcpBrowserHost OnTick() winbrowserhost.cpp:530
86  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CXcpDispatcher Tick() xcpwindow.cpp:1350
87  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CXcpDispatcher OnReentrancyProtectedWindowMessage() xcpwindow.cpp:910
88  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CXcpDispatcher WindowProc() xcpwindow.cpp:746
89  user32.dll  UserCallWinProcCheckWow() clmsg.c:233
90  user32.dll  DispatchMessageWorker() clmsg.c:3094
91  Windows.UI.dll  Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher ProcessMessage() dispatcher.cpp:315
92  Windows.UI.dll  Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher WaitAndProcessMessagesInternal() dispatcher.cpp:1766
93  Windows.UI.dll  Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher ProcessEvents() dispatcher.cpp:569
94  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll CJupiterWindow RunCoreWindowMessageLoop() jupiterwindow.cpp:1234
95  Windows.UI.Xaml.dll DirectUI::DXamlCore RunMessageLoop() dxamlcore.cpp:2062
96  twinapi.appcore.dll Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView Run() coreapplicationview.cpp:1695
97  twinapi.appcore.dll _lambda_fffaad44dee747f80f4a19ad58cc9ca3_ operator() coreapplicationview.cpp:1149
98  SHCore.dll  _WrapperThreadProc() thread.cpp:321
99  kernel32.dll    BaseThreadInitThunk() thread.c:64
100 ntdll.dll   RtlUserThreadStart() rtlstrt.c:997
```

Comment: Does your app work well in debug and release mode?

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes it appears on a dev device in DEBUG or RELEASE. But I can't reproduce it easily, and VS does can't handle it. It's very confusing. Do you know how to find the originate exception details ?

Comment: Would you try to create a simple reproducible sample so that we can look into and troubleshoot it?

Comment: My app has is quite big, and I don't know which page cause the isue… that's why I try to find the real error to determinate the origin. Do you know anything about method that raise the exception ? (BinaryFormatObjectWriter SetValueOnCurrentInstance() binaryformatobjectwriter.cpp:654)

Comment: It is hard to find why this issue happens, a simplest but heavy way is to step by step to create a new project to see where the issue happens with configure the VS debugger application type to Mixed(Managed and Native).

Comment: By the way, do you use the Microsoft advertising control?

Comment: Nop, we don't use the MS advertising control. Is there a way to access the UWP Xaml framework reference source code like .NET WPF reference source ? It would defenitively be great to help debug this kind of issue.

Comment: As we can see the issue is due to a parse error in their XAML. But without being able to reproduce the problem we don’t have enough information to really be able to help. Could you try to create a reproducible sample so that we can look into this issue?

Comment: @PascalFresnay any progress over this problem? I've also got a similar situation like yours.

Comment: @doedoe : no, i'm still facing this issue :-( Let me know if you find a way to get rid of it

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT I've made a reproducible sample for this one, can you check it out on my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

My solution might vary to others who got a similar problem like this, but It seems that systems running on FCU build ( 1803 or 17134 ) or possibly lower(?) have a problem when parsing `CornerRadius`, hence why `WrapErrorWithParserErrorAndRethrow()` got called.

I've made a reproducible sample on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Nexxkinn/StowedException_sample) that might produces the same error as the original poster might be.

As for the solution, the easiest one is to just commented out all `CornerRadius` attribute in my project and it runs perfectly now in my case.